# What does "bipartite" mean?

Tags: entanglement, terminology-and-notation

This is a really easy question, but my mother language is not English and I get confused quite a lot reading Preskill notes.

What does a bipartite system mean? Is this just that it "lives" in a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces? Does it mean that the system is separable? I just want a clear definition of what bipartite means (without any other special conditions on it), so that I can know for sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What does a bipartite system mean?

I'll summarize the main definitions below (adapted from [Quantiki](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite-states-and-schmidt-decomposition)).

- **Bipartite system and states**: If Alice's subsystem is described by the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$ and Bob's is described by $\mathcal{H}_B$, the compound bipartite system is described by the tensor product of the two spaces, $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$. State vectors and density operators on $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ are called bipartite quantum states.
- **Bipartite pure state**:  Let $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ be a Hilbert space defined as a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$. We call some [**pure state**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Pure_states) $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}$ on the composite system $A\cup B$ **bipartite**, if it is written with respect to the partition $AB$, which means $|\Psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{ij}c_{ij} |i\rangle_A|j\rangle_B$, where $\{|i\rangle_A\}$ and $\{|j\rangle_B\}$ are bases in $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$ respectively. Note that if $\mathcal{H}_A$ has a basis $\{|i\rangle_A\}$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$ has a basis $\{|j\rangle_B\}$ then then $\{|i\rangle_A\otimes |j\rangle_B\}$ is automatically a basis for $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$.
- **Bipartite mixed state**: Let $\rho_{AB}$ be a mixed state on a composite system $A\cup B$. Then we say $\rho_{AB}$ is a bipartite [**mixed state**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states) on $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$ and write $\rho_{AB}=\sum_{ij}p_{ij}\rho_{A}^i\otimes \rho_{B}^j$ where $\{\rho_A^i\}$ and $\{\rho_B^j\}$ are bases of density operators in $A$ and $B$ respectively. Note that if $\mathcal{H}_A$ has a basis of density operators $\{\rho_A^i\}$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$ has a basis of density operators $\{\rho_B^j\}$ then then $\{\rho_A^i\otimes \rho_B^j\}$ is automatically a basis for mixed states on $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes \mathcal{H}_B$.

> Is this just that it "lives" in a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces?

Almost, yes.

> Does it mean that the system is separable?

No, not necessarily. You might want to read the Wikipedia page on [Separable state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_state).

There exist bipartite pure states $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}$ which *cannot* be written as $|\Psi_1\rangle_A\otimes |\Psi_2\rangle_B$ for $|\Psi_1\rangle_A\in \mathcal{H}_A$ and $|\Psi_2\rangle_B\in \mathcal{H}_B$. A bipartite state $|\Psi\rangle_{AB}$ will separable if and only if it lies in the image of the [Segre embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) $$\iota: \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^1  \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B) \cong \mathbb{C}P^3,$$ $$([x_1 : y_1],[x_2 : y_2]) \mapsto [x_1x_2:x_1y_2:y_1x_2:y_1y_2]$$ as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/141177).

Similarly, not every mixed state $\rho_{AB}$ can be written as a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of product states (i.e. given $p_k\geq 0$ and $\sum_kp_k=1$) $$\rho_{AB}=\sum_kp_k\rho_A^k\otimes\rho_B^k$$ where $\{\rho_A^k\}$ and $\{\rho_B^k\}$ are bases of mixed states on subsystems $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Interestingly, unlike bipartite pure states, deciding whether an arbitrary density matrix $\rho_{AB}$ is a [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem cf. [Gurvits, 2003](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303055) and [this TCS SE discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32122). So in general there are no nice set of rules to distinguish between entangled and separable bipartite mixed states. This is also an open research problem.

For a detailed treatment of quantum entanglement go through [arXiv:quant-ph/0702225](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702225).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your question cleared up almost everything for me. Just to be sure, for the pure bipartite system you say that: $|\Psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{ij}c_{ij} |i\rangle_A|j\rangle_B$, where $\{|i\rangle_A\}$ and $\{|j\rangle_B\}$ are bases in $H_A$ and $H_B$ respectively. So I assume writing it like this does not mean that the bipartite system is seperable (as you mentioned), although you can write the "terms" in $\rho$ like $|i\rangle_A|j\rangle_B$. Being seperable you should be able to write them like $(|i_1\rangle_A + |i_2\rangle_A +....) (  |j_1\rangle_B + |j_2\rangle_B + ...)$, right?

Comment: @CFRedDemon Almost correct. You can write a separable pure state as $$(a_1|i_1\rangle+a_2|i_2\rangle+\cdots)\otimes (b_1|j_1\rangle+b_2|j_2\rangle+\cdots).$$ An arbitrary $|\Psi\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{ij}c_{ij} |i\rangle_A|j\rangle_B$ cannot be written in that form. For example, you won't be able to write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ as a tensor product of two single-qubit states. But say $\frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle+|11\rangle)$ can be written as $$\left(\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\right)_A\otimes \left(\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\right)_B$$.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the constants, but that was just because I typed too fast, I think I get it now. Thanks a lot! I was just getting confused with all the terminology in my notes as and the Internet was not clearing it up.