# What is a bipartite unitary?

Tags: quantum-gate, unitarity, terminology-and-notation

What is a 'bipartite unitary'? I saw it appearing in a paper "Efficient verification of quantum gates with local operations" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.14032.pdf)

A reference to the definition is very much appreciated.

Comment: A unitary acting on a bipartite system?

Comment: I am curious, is your user name based off the league of legends character? and yes I would think that makes sense. I am trying to find a reference to the definition.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6052/55

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 You got me

Answer (score 1):

Take operators $A_n$ and $B_n$ that act on systems $a$ and $b$ respectively. A bipartite unitary can be written as
$$
U=\exp(i \sum_n A_n\otimes B_n),
$$ any time that the construction $\sum_n A_n\otimes B_n$ is Hermitian.

Comment: how does the exp of a matrix equal a matrix?

Comment: do you have a reference anywhere for this definition?

Comment: also, does Rammus' comment suffice as an answer? "A unitary acting on a bipartite system"

Comment: Yes, Rammus's comment is correct. Then, unitary operators $U$ can always be constructed as exponentials of Hermitian operators $H$ via $U=\exp(i H)$, so any bipartite Hermitian operator $H$ can be used to create a bipartite unitary operator $U$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: I see, why not just state what Rammus said as the answer? Seems much simpler. Or does your answer add additional restrictions to the definition?...

Comment: They are the same, I just spelled out what a unitary acting on a bipartite system must look like.